# poisson distribution expectation question

Tags: probability

A statistics instructor has put 4 copies of his lecture notes in the library reserve section.
Let X represent the number of students who come in to borrow these notes. Suppose X
has a Poisson distribution with parameter  lambda = 3. Find the expected number of copies
that have been borrowed. (Note: No more than 4 copies in total can be borrowed.)

So what should I do to solve this? I have no idea how to approach...hope someone can give me some hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the number of copies borrowed.

You can easily write down the probabilities that $Y=0$, $Y=1$, $Y=2$, and $Y=3$. They are the same as the corresponding Poisson probabilities for $X$.

But $4$ is different, since $Y=4$ precisely if $X\ge 4$. Thus the probability that $Y=4$ is $1-(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3))$.

Now you know the full distribution of $Y$, so you can find $E(Y)$ as usual.

**Remark:** There are fancier ways to approach this problem, by figuring out how the expectation of $Y$ differs from the known expectation of $X$.

Comment: wait $P(Y=20)$ is it 2 instead?

Comment: Yes, I have trouble with my shift key, it sometimes is sticky, so I get a $0$ when a parenthesis is intended. Fixed.

Comment: May i ask why $X \ge 4$ cannot be found by just using the same way as the 0 to 3? like i know if $X \ge 4$ it would become $1- P(X \lt 4)$ but i dun understand why

Comment: Well, $\Pr(X\ge 4)$ is an **infinite** sum of terms like the ones for $0,1,2,3$. I didn't really want to add infinitely many numbers.